# Azure Analysis Service pricing inconsistency

Tags: price, azure-analysis-services

I was creating Azure Analysis Service from Portal and observed that B2 tier pricing is being shown significantly lower than B1 when one clicks on "view full pricing link". I checked the normal [analysis service pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/analysis-services/) and see there B2 is priced higher than B1 which it should be. Is the pricing shown on the "view full pricing link" erroneous?
[Portal image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ghNB.png)